# JPA: How to get Id after persist in standalone java app

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

This is a standalone java application, not web application. So when I persist the object like this

```
public <T> T create(T t) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(t);
    em.flush();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return t;
}
```

The `id` inside the `T t` object is still null, even though a new row with correct data and id is created correctly inside the database. Usually in my web app that utilize `@EJB`, the `id` available right after I persist, since it persist the entity object into my persistence context, I am not sure if I have my persistence context here?

This is how I mapped my id inside my @Entity Class

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

also I make the id of this table in the database `AUTO_INCREMENT`, like this

```
CREATE TABLE Config
(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

This is how I obtain my EntityManager

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CorePU");
em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Here is what inside my `persistence.xml`

```
<persistence-unit name="CorePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>    
<class>com.wf.docsys.core.model.Config</class>    
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XNINFODB"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxx"/>
</properties>
```

Please help, I am not sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: The key for me at least is to return the persisted object. And then use the returned one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is my answer. Tested**

When mapping your Id, switch from what I have above, which is

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

to

```
@Entity
public class Person {
   @Id
   @TableGenerator(name="TABLE_GEN", table="SEQUENCE_TABLE", pkColumnName="SEQ_NAME",
       valueColumnName="SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue="PERSON_SEQ")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="TABLE_GEN")
   private long id;
   ...
}
```

Since I use microsoft SQL server, I have to use `@TableGenerator`. More information can be found here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Table_sequencing

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a `@GeneratedValue` on your id field.

Answer (score 1):

As I found on [this post](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic25646.html) the EntityManager have a method called [refresh](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29) that will update your object after you persist him.

So your code will probably looks like this:

```
public <T> T create(T t) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(t);
    em.refresh(t);
    em.flush();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return t;
}
```

I haven't tested this, so I'm not sure where exactly to put the refresh method call, there, after the commit, after the flush, etc.

Hope it can help you.

Good luck.

Comment: refresh is unnecessary there. Just do flush(). That forces the persist, and hence obtaining the id (once the user has added GeneratedValue annotation of course).

Comment: @DataNucleus: Yup, I have posted my answer below, since I cannot use `@SequenceGenerator`, I use `@TableGenerator with `@GeneratedValue` and it works. However, will calling `flush()` every time cause performance problem, DataNucleus?

Comment: @DataNucleus: flush() worked for me. You should post an answer. And if your well versed enough also address Thang Pham's performance concern.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not a persist but the merge will do the same thing more simply. I wrap my persist in an actual merge operation which will save the entity if it does not exist.

```
public T persist(T obj) {
    EntityManager em = ThreadLocalPersistenceManager.getEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        obj = em.merge(obj);
    } finally {
        if (! tx.getRollbackOnly()) {
            tx.commit();
        }
    }

    return obj;
}


/**
 * This will save the object and return the id of the persisted object.
 *  
 * @param obj
 * @return The id of the persisted object.
 */
public Long save(T obj) {
    persist(obj);
    return obj.getId();
}
```