# Java Swing / JPA / Oracle inserting twice

Tags: java

Probably a newbie Java...thing but here it is. Using JPA to call a INSERT stored procedure to an Oracle 11g database. Everything works fine in terms of getting the data to the DB table.

I've wrapped the JPA code into a Java Swing application. My problem is the data gets submitted twice somehow or another. I have a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` that displays when I submit the data. That only shows once. But when I query the table, there are two entries in the table. Here's my code....

**Button code**

```
JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        AddNewCustomer();
    }
});
btnSubmit.setBounds(24, 341, 91, 23);
frmNewCustomer.getContentPane().add(btnSubmit);
```

**Action methods**

```
public void AddNewCustomer() {
    Customer.AddCustomer(this.txtFirstName.getText(),
            this.txtLastName.getText(), this.txtAddress.getText(),
            this.txtCity.getText(), this.txtState.getText(),
            this.txtEmail.getText(), this.txtPhone.getText());

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmNewCustomer, "Added new customer",
            "Status", 1);
}

protected static void AddCustomer(String sFirstName, String sLastName,
        String sAddress, String sCity, String sState, String sEmail,
        String sPhone) {
    try {
        factory = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("AddCustomer");
        q.setParameter("p_PHONE", sPhone);
        q.setParameter("p_STATE", sState);
        q.setParameter("p_FIRST_NAME", sFirstName);
        q.setParameter("p_ADDRESS", sAddress);
        q.setParameter("p_EMAIL", sEmail);
        q.setParameter("p_CITY", sCity);
        q.setParameter("p_LAST_NAME", sLastName);
        int r = q.executeUpdate();
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        List results = q.getResultList();
        if (results != null) {
            Object id = results.get(0);
            if (id != null) {
                System.out.println(id.toString());
            }
        }
        em.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you remove `List results = q.getResultList();` (and the following lines)?

Comment: The reson I was doing that was to get the newly created ID from and OUT parameter from the the Insert SPROC. The SPROC has a trigger that does Sequence.nextVal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the call to `getResultList()`, this is executing the same query again (and it's an insert query, not a select query). You shouldn't need that to get the IDs anyway, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035973/jpa-how-to-get-id-after-persist-in-standalone-java-app). You don't need to use a query for this at all however as the appropriate way of creating an entry should be using `entityManager.persist(obj)` (assuming you have a JPA entity for it, which you should since you're using JPA anyway).

Comment: The question mentions a stored procedure used to do the insert, which is probably the reason for use of a named query.

Comment: Ah. Nevertheless he needs to not execute the insert query twice. You'd need to create a second query and do a select, although that won't easily guarantee you get the right object back in a multi-threaded environment. Depending on what the stored procedure does it may be desirable to replace it with a trigger instead and use JPA the way it's intended to be used.

Comment: Almost offtopic: To stay safe in multiuser/multithreaded envirnment, the 2nd query would have to be executed in the same transaction as the 1st and using a correct isolation level. But in this case it seems it's best to just leave that out. Complete offtopic: I still wish there will be somewhat better support of stored procedures in Java ORMs one day. I'm not a fan of them, but (usually for reasons beyond my control) I keep hitting them on every other project.

Comment: Okay... from that link you provided, it suggests to use @GeneratedValue which generates an ID in the table, correct? I specifically excluded that because I have a trigger that uses Sequence.nextVal which works fine.  

I used the q.getResultList() to get the OUT parameter from the stored procedure which contains newly created ID. The stored Proc returns  Sequence.currval

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Changed code to....

```
protected static void AddCustomer(String sFirstName,String sLastName, String sAddress, String sCity, String sState,String sEmail,String sPhone )
{

    try {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("AddCustomer");   
        q.setParameter("p_PHONE", sPhone);
        q.setParameter("p_STATE", sState);
        q.setParameter("p_FIRST_NAME", sFirstName);
        q.setParameter("p_ADDRESS", sAddress);
        q.setParameter("p_EMAIL", sEmail);
        q.setParameter("p_CITY", sCity);
        q.setParameter("p_LAST_NAME", sLastName);
        //int r = q.executeUpdate();                
        //em.getTransaction().commit();

        List results = q.getResultList();
        if(results != null)
        {           
            Object id = results.get(0);
            if(id != null)
            {
                System.out.println(id.toString());
            }
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        em.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```